# Flask separate models into multiple files

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, model, python-import

I'm setting up a new Flask app, where I want to have all of my `SQLAlchemy` models in separate files. The overall structure should end up looking like this:

```
flask-app
|
|--api
|   |--user.py
|   |--example.py
|
|--controllers
|   |--user.py
|   |--example.py
|
|--models
|   |--user.py
|   |--example.py
|
|-main.py
|-modelref.py
|-config.py
```

In terms of code here's what i have so far:

`main.py:`

```
import os

from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

import modelref
from apiref import load_api


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='./../react/public')
app.config.from_object(os.getenv("APP_SETTINGS", "config.Development"))
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)


@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')
    
load_api(app)
```

The `modelref` import is a shorthand of sorts. In the `modelref.py` file I import every model that I have in the `models` folder like so:

`modelref.py`:

```
from models.user import User
from models.example import Example
```

Then the model itself is something along the lines of:

`models/user.py`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username =  db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    registered_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, username, email, password, first_name, last_name):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password, flask.current_app.config.get('BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS')).decode()
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.registered_on = datetime.datetime.now()

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

The model gets manipulated in a controller class defined here:

`controllers/user.py`:

```
class UserController:

    @staticmethod
    def register(username: str, password: str, email: str, first_name: str, last_name: str) -> dict:
        result: dict = {}
        try:
            user = User(
                    username=username,
                    password=password,
                    email=email,
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name
                )
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            User.rollback()
            raise ResourceExists("user already exists")
            
        return login(user.username, user.password);
            
    @staticmethod
    def login(username: str, password: str):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                token = user.encode_auth_token(user.id)
                return {
                    "username": user.username,
                    "first_name": user.first_name,
                    "last_name": user.last_name,
                    "token": token
                }
            else:
                abort(400, "Invalid Password")
        else:
            abort(404, "User Not Found")
```

The controller is accessed in an API resource defined using pluggable views. The views and routes are registered with the app in the `load_app(app)` method. I'm not sharing that whole pipeline, because I believe it is out of scope, but if anyone believes it's not, than I will add it into the post.

So now here's the problem. If I try to access the model in the code or run `flask db migrate`, I get an error that `db` is not defined.

A solution I've seen is to add a `db=SQLAlchemy` line in the model, but then the `flask db migrate` doesn't find this model, likely because the mentioned line creates a new `SQLAlchemy` instance, so it's essentially unaware of the models existence.

With this setup I'm unable to import the `db` object from `main` since that causes a circular import due to the model being imported in the controller.

Is there a way I can pass a reference to `db` to the model without an import, or make the model search for the "current" instance of 'db'. Or is there any way to reorganize the main code so that I can maintain the general structure, but be able to run migrations?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that in a case such as mine, the best option is to apply the application factory pattern. I now have an `app.py` module, where I initialize all the modules I need in a `create_app` method like so:

`app.py:`

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='./../react/public')
    app.config.from_object(os.getenv("APP_SETTINGS", "config.Development"))
    import modelref
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    
    return app
```

And them my `main.py` file simply invokes the `create_app` method and then sets up routes and API resources like so:

`main.py:`

```
from flask import send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS

from apiref import load_api
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
CORS(app)

@app.route("/", defaults={'path':''})
def serve(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder,'index.html')
    
load_api(app)
```

Running `import modelref` within the `create_model` method makes all the models imported in `modelref` visible to the app and the `flask db` commands.